# Setting up VSFTPD permissions with Apache server

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have a VM running Ubuntu 10.10. I'm using Netbeans and uploading files to an ftp on the virtual machine. I'm using vsftpd.

The problem I'm having is, the owner of the folder `/var/www` is the user `apache` in order for the apache server to be able to read the files. So far so good.

But when I try to upload a file from ftp user `user1` I'm not able to. I know what the problem is. My question is, how do I set up permissions correctly for the user `apache` and `user1` to be able to write/read all the files in /var/www directory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a group `www-users` and make it the group owner of `/var/www`.  Then assign the users `apache` and `user1` to the group and set the permissons on the `/var/www` directory to 775.  This will allow `user1` and any other users in the `www-users` group to read and write to `/var/www`; it will also make it easier to authorize other users to write to `/var/www` — simply assign the user to the `www-users` group.

**Edit:** The correct permissions on `/var/www` is 2775, which includes setgid so that files and directories inside `/var/www` inherit the group ownership of `/var/www`.

Comment: Great answer. Except apache isn't able to read the files after I upload something with `user1` I ran the following commands: `chown -R apache:www-users /var/www`, `usermod -g www-users apache`, `usermod -g www-users user1`, `chmod 775 /var/www`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The umask may be set to deny read permissions from others; see if changing the umask helps.

Comment: Yep. That was part of it.

Comment: Here are the steps in case any googlers need a hint.

`1) set up vsftpd for umask 0027 (/etc/vsftpd.conf) [local_umask=0027]`

`2) create www-users group (groupadd www-users)`

`3) add user to group (usermod -a -G group user)`

`4) Set apache to run as www-users group (httpd.conf)`

`5) chgrp www-users /var/www`

`6) chmod 2775 /var/www`

Comment: Also, try adding setgid permission to the directory: `chmod g+s /var/www`.  This will ensure that files and directories created inside the directory are owned by the group that owns the directory.

Comment: Super awesome. Thanks a bunch @DragonLord =) Edit: I was about to use the chmod g+s until I read your edit. Step 6 I had already used permission 2775 so it looks like I'm good :)

Comment: Thanks, finding all useful info in the same post is nice:)